# Select Subset in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to write a linq query which will exclude any records that have a child record with a certain integer ID.

The class I am querying against looks like:

```
public class Group {
     public ICollection<Item> { get; set; } // This is the child collection
}

public class Item {
     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My repository query method is:

```
public ICollection<Group> Get(int itemId) {

      return from c in Set.... // Set is an EF collection of all Groups
}
```

I want to return all `Groups` that do not have an `Item` in their `Items` collection with the `Id` equal to the `itemId` passed to the method.

Not sure how to write this most efficiently in Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work (I'm using method syntax though as I prefer method syntax above query syntax for anything other than joins):

```
var result = db.Groups.Where(g => !g.Items.Any(i => i.Id == itemID)).ToList();
```

Select all groups which don't contain an item with an `Id` equal to `itemID`. By the way I notice you have `Set` in your code? Does this mean you already fetched all the groups beforehand or something (so filtering in memory)? The easiest way is to work with your `DbContext` and access your tables from there.

Comment: Thanks - brain freeze day.  Set is from DbContext and not preloaded - long story but looks like that as a result of a generic base class.

Comment: @Graham Happens, it's still early in the day ;-) (for me at least)